Date Parsing Issue with Discord Invite API Response in Google Apps Script
I am trying to make a function that will validate a Discord invite and check if the invite is temporary just from a Discord invite URL. If the invite is temporary, I want it to return the expiration date as a new Date. If it doesn't expire, I want the function to return false.
async function getInviteExpiration(inviteUrl) {
  // Extract the invite code from the URL
  const regex = /discord\.gg\/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/;
  const match = inviteUrl.match(regex);
  if (!match) {
    throw new Error('Invalid invite URL');
  }

  const inviteCode = match[1];

  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(`https://discord.com/api/invites/${inviteCode}?with_counts=true`);
  if (response.getResponseCode() !== 200) {
    throw new Error('Failed to fetch discord invite information');
  }

  const inviteData = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  console.log(inviteData.expires_at);  // Temporary, just for testing
  console.log(new Date(inviteData.expires_at));  // Temporary, just for testing
  if (inviteData.expires_at === null) {
    return false; // Invite never expires
  } else {
    return new Date(inviteData.expires_at); // Return expiration date
  }
}

I made a test function to test getInviteExpiration.
function test() {
  const permanentUrl = "https://discord.gg/minecraft";
  console.log(getInviteExpiration(permanentUrl)); // Expecting false
  
  const tempUrl = "https://discord.gg/DdMJXskh";
  console.log(getInviteExpiration(tempUrl)); // Expecting Date
}

And here is the outputted console,
null
Wed Dec 31 1969 18:00:00 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)
{}
2024-04-18T02:27:18+00:00
Wed Apr 17 2024 21:27:18 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
{}

Why is it that I'm getting empty objects when in the getInviteExpiration function, it was able to parse console.log(new Date(inviteData.expires_at))?

If my understanding of your current issue Why is it that I'm getting empty objects when in the getInviteExpiration function, it was able to parse console.log(new Date(inviteData.expires_at))? is correct, I guessed that the reason for your current issue was due to async. So, how about the following modification?
Modified script 1:
In this modification, async is removed. In this modification, only getInviteExpiration is modified.
From:
async function getInviteExpiration(inviteUrl) {

To:
function getInviteExpiration(inviteUrl) {

Modified script 2:
If you are required to use async, how about the following modification? In this modification, only test is modified.
From:
function test() {
  const permanentUrl = "https://discord.gg/minecraft";
  console.log(getInviteExpiration(permanentUrl)); // Expecting false
  
  const tempUrl = "https://discord.gg/DdMJXskh";
  console.log(getInviteExpiration(tempUrl)); // Expecting Date
}

To:
async function test() {
  const permanentUrl = "https://discord.gg/minecraft";
  console.log(await getInviteExpiration(permanentUrl)); // Expecting false

  const tempUrl = "https://discord.gg/DdMJXskh";
  console.log(await getInviteExpiration(tempUrl)); // Expecting Date
}


Modified script 1 was the answer, thank you!
